# Поиск повторяющихся строк на ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Нужно проверить все файлы директории на пример повторяющихся строк, и вывести строки, которые повторяются более 1о раза + сколько раз они встречаются

Comment: А свои мысли и наработки по данному вопросу какие-нибудь имеются?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
cat * | sort | uniq -cd
```

[`cat`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat)`*` Вывести всё из текущего каталога
[`sort`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort) Отсортировать строки
[`uniq`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) выводим повторяющиеся строки, `-c` -- выводим количество, `-d` только те, что больше одного раза встретились.

Comment: `grep -H . *` вместо `cat *` добавит интересного ;)

Comment: @0andriy, ключ `-H` используется в `grep` по умолчанию при поиске более чем в одном файле.

Comment: @zombic, именно, но в вопросе неясно, требуется ли общую картину или по-файлово.